# What is the right way to maintain Time Machine backup history for a HDD with two partitions?

Tags: time-machine, backup, time-capsule, partition

I have two user partitions (not counting any hidden/system ones like Lion Restore etc.) on my MacBook Pro's internal HDD: Volume_A (100 GB) and Volume_B (20 GB). My Time Capsule has been keeping everything backed up nicely for a little over a year now.

I now want to re-partition my volumes (no change in names). Volume_A: 100 -> 70 GB and Volume_B: 20 -> 50 GB.

Since I also have access to a CCC backup of both partitions, I can easily delete Volume_B, recreate it with the new, increased size and restore the data into it from the CCC backup.

My question is: will Time Machine/Capsule be able to retain the history after the new partition scheme goes live? Or will it decide to wipe the slate clean and start with a fresh backup of the newly re-partitioned setup?

Is there any way to make sure I don't lose my history and have backups "continue" and build upon the existing collection?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so it looks like there is no need to worry about losing backup history on the time-capsule as long as the names of the volumes are unchanged.

Since there were no answers here, I just bit the bullet and went ahead with what I had originally intended to do. Fortunately, TC picked up the deltas after I resized and restored the data into Volume_B.

So now you might be wondering why I even bothered to ask in the first place. Well, the reason I was concerned is because the first time around, when I went from a single partition layout (backed up on TC) to a dual partition layout (with the name of the first partition unchanged), TC had somehow decided that it needed to start from a clean slate, and I lost all the history there.